# C# Timeline control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I have an SQLite-database-backed for fast searching and log access.

I'm now designing on how to select date range for the log view. I'm thinking of a graphical timeline, which can be mouse-navigated, with zooming capability so that you can drill down to hour/minute-spans if need be or if the zooming capability is too complex ( then just have a text box of start & end date between which the timeline is shown ) . There are different log message types (5 or 6) and i would like to indicate each by a different colour on the timeline

This looks very good visually:

[www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtltimeline.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtltimeline.aspx)

A C# .Net version of that (open-source) or similar would be great.

Does anyone have something like that that they would recommend? I'd love to avoid having to code my own control from scratch. Help requested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use that control into another assembly (DLL) and reference it?

**Edit**: You may like [this control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/RangeControl.aspx). It's a general range selector but you may easily modify it to your needs.

Comment: tbh, im not sure how to do it ? I figured it was WTL and I wanted a Winforms control

Comment: @techmanc Oops I missed that... But I don't even know what that means... Or about compatibility... I am not sure...